# Execute TestNG tests in parallel, one browser is not closing

Tags: java, selenium, testng

```
/**
 * Before method is executed before any test case
 *
 * @throws Exception
 */
@BeforeMethod(alwaysRun = true)
public void openBrowser() throws Exception {
    driver = browserService.openBrowser(globalProperties);
    driver.get(getAUTurl("salesforce.app.url"));

    }


/**
 * After method is executed before any test case
 *
 * @throws Exception
 */
@AfterMethod(alwaysRun = true)
public void closeBrowser() throws Exception {
    driver.quit();
}

 //Above shown is my baseTestcase which has 2 methods beforemethod and after
 //method.

public class SanityTest extends BaseTestcase {
public static String downloadedFilePath;


    @Test   public void test1() {   }
    @Test   public void test2() {   }
```

Then I create following tests suite

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Selenium TestNG Suite" parallel="methods" thread-count="2" >
<test name="Sanity test">
    <classes>
      <class name="com.prahs.tests.PAWS.SanityTest "/>
    </classes>
</test>
</suite>
```

But one browser is not closing after execution?

Comment: I had to do some substantial reformatting for this code - please take a moment to learn the code formatting tool here. Basically it is just paste, select and click!

Answer (score 0):

Just a educated guess: you are using method level parallel execution of methods, and the driver you are calling quit() on is not the only instance of WebDriver.

Try this with threadCount 1 or w/o parallel execution to check this and make sure to assiciate the driver instance with the te current thread if using parallel execution.

Answer (score 0):

We struggled with a similar situation with our testing efforts. We also wanted to leverage the TestNG parallelization along with Selenium web driver. Unfortunately, managing the web driver life cycle within each test class or trying to use a static class holding the web driver wasn't effective when enabling any of the TestNG parallel modes. Matching classes and methods under test with the active TestNG thread and the instantiated web driver was unwieldy when it worked at all. We were spending more time figuring out the web driver lifecycles than getting to the real web application tests.

In your case since you've defined `<suite parallel="methods">` when TestNG executes the classes are instantiated on one thread with all the appropriate @ annotations being processed. However, with the 'methods' parallel mode, TestNG instantiates each of the test classes methods on separate threads. These threads are unaware and unable to make use of any processed annotations that may have started a web driver, static or otherwise. Additionally, I believe too that, the answer from sschuth is correct. Your @BeforeMethod is called twice. Once when TestNG instantiates the class the first time and then again when TestNG instantiates the test class' method on another separate thread.

We have an open source project that abstracts away the web driver lifecycle management for TestNG/Selenium testing. It properly supports each of the TestNG parallel modes providing the correct and active web driver for each test class method under test. It's helped us greatly in our testing efforts. Perhaps it may be of use in your case as well. Or if nothing else give you an idea of how you might tackle it differently. The project is over on GitHub as [Concurrent Selenium TestNG (COSENG)](https://github.com/siostechcorp/coseng). Kind regards.